# Automatically send reports in Email with Cumulocity

Tags: report, complex-event-processing, cumulocity

In Cumulocity I want to send configured reports automatically in Emails after a certain time period elapsed. Usually reports are sent manually.
I already have a CEP (Complex Event Processing) rule that automatically sends me the Emails, without the report content though.

I am stuck trying to access the configured report templates in the CEP rule.

Does anybody know how and if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about the reports in cockpit application.

Currently there is no possibility to trigger the sending of the report from CEP.

What you could do is create a script that you run yourself (e.g. cron) on your own system/server that does the same REST call that the UI also does to trigger the report sending.